# docker does not bind 0.0.0.0 but 127.0.0.1 only

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker compose file creaeting multiple containers.
It looks that docker ports are only bound to 127.0.0.1, but not to 0.0.0.0

This is an extract of the docker compose file, quite simple:

```
  database:
    image: mariadb:11.2
    container_name: ua-database
    environment:
      - MARIADB_ROOT_USER=root
      - MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=1231231
      - MYSQL_TCP_PORT= 3308
    ports:
      - "3308:3308"
    restart: unless-stopped
```

I have the same issue if I test test with "0.0.0.0:3308:3308" or with my IP "192.168.10.153:3308:3308" (in this case, localhost do not works any more, normal).

It was working perfectly, but stop working 2 days ago without any change. The same configuration work very well on the other developer host.

I can access to the database with 127.0.0.1, but not with my IP.

what I get with docker ps -a (port looks to be binded to 0.0.0.0)
[image]

I cannot connect with my IP (I use curl just to test the connection to mysql):
[image]

It's 2 days I'm searching, but not I'm stuck, of course 2 days before the release....

Any clue? Thanks.

Comment: `- MYSQL_TCP_PORT= 3308` try to remove the space before `= 3308`, i dough is that, but you never know

Comment: Does it work if you don't set `MYSQL_TCP_PORT` at all, and set the second `ports:` number to the standard MySQL port 3306 (so `ports: ['3308:3306']`)?

Comment: Thanks Jacques & DAvid for your reply, but it still not working.
I remove bitdefender and all the security, firewall.. 
I'm running Windows 11 latest version.

The port number are fine since I can connect with the loopback 127.0.0.1.
Still searching...

Comment: Well, "Windows" might be an important "detail". You should clarify how you run docker, how do you try to connect (WSL, powershell) and maybe provide even more information. "Without any change" may not be correct - updates may have been installed during the last days. Have you applied them? Have you rebooted?

Comment: If you are using Docker for Windows, the containers are actually running within a VM on your machine and it is likely the containers are only published over this address, meaning the IP address is different from your localhost. Check guides how to find out IP address of your docker VM and then try with that one.

Comment: I removed all the virtualization, WSL, hyper/V and re-install from scratch and it works now.
Probably there were a kind of mess in the ip routing.
Thanks all.